# Multi-level object inheritance in JavaScript with `super` keyword

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I want to compose multiple objects into one. The `super` keyword should call corresponding parent object method. If parent's method is not present, it should call next parent's method and so on.

Example code that throws:

```js
var base = {
  runBusinessLogic() {
    console.log('BASE');
  }
}

var concrete = {

  unrelatedExtraMethod() {
  }
}

var addon = {
  runBusinessLogic() {
    super.runBusinessLogic(); // I expect this super call to call base.runBusinessLogic(..)
    console.log('ADDON');
  }
}

var layer2 = Object.setPrototypeOf(concrete, base);
var layer3 = Object.create(layer2, addon);

layer3.runBusinessLogic(); // throws "TypeError: layer3.runBusinessLogic is not a function"
```

I expect the `layer3.runBusinessLogic(..)` to call `base.runBusinessLogic(..)` and still have callable `unrelatedExtraMethod` on itself.

How to make the `super` keyword work as outlined?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    var base = {
      runBusinessLogic() {
        console.log('BASE');
      }
    }

    var concrete = {

      unrelatedExtraMethod() {
      }
    }

    var addon = {
      runBusinessLogic() {
        super.runBusinessLogic(); // I expect this super call to call base.runBusinessLogic(..)
        console.log('ADDON');
      }
    }

    var layer2 = Object.setPrototypeOf(concrete, base);
    var layer3 = Object.setPrototypeOf(addon, layer2); // change this

    layer3.runBusinessLogic()
```